# How do I reference an anonymous module from itself in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an external modules situation in my code. According to the recommendations (see "[Needless namespacing](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript&version=12)") I am trying to avoid unnecessary namespaces and remove module declarations from everywhere. Now I ran into naming conflicts when a parameter of a function in the module has the same as the name of another function in the module. So I wish I could somehow tell the compiler that it's not the parameter it's a another function from the current module that I need to call. Consider:

```
function a() {
}
function b(a: {}) {
  return a(); /// <--- a problem, I wish there was something like: module.a(); or global::a();
}
```

Is there a way to somehow overcome this problem without changing the names?

Answer (score 0):

```
function a() {
}
function b(a: {}) {
  return this.a(); ///try using this
}
```

I'd rather suggest to do it like this:

```
module Testing {
    class MyFuncs {
        public a = () => { }
        public b = (a: {}) => { return this.a()}

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, although it might work, I don't like this workaround because `this` is of type `any` with all the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

For modules, if you exporting the `a` function you can access it via the module name. For the global items, you would need to extend the interface representing the global root in order to give the compiler knowledge of the additional item. I have shown examples of both below.

```
// Module
module Example {
    export function a() {
        alert('A1');
    }

    export function b(a: {}) {
      Example.a(); /// <--- I wish there was something like: module.a();
    }
}

Example.b({});

// Global
interface Window {
    a: () => any;
}

function a() {
    alert('A2');
}

function b(a: {}) {
  return window.a(); /// <--- I wish there was something like: global::a();
}

b({});
```

If neither of these works for you, perhaps it is possible to change your design to wrap the methods in a class as class members are accessed using the `this` keyword, which distinguishes them from local variables and parameters.